# laravel undefined index error while retrieving notification data from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have created notification to store order submit event as

```
 return [
       'cart_id'=>$this->cart->id,
       'text'=>'order is submitted'
    ];
```

when i retrieve notifications data from database as

```
 @foreach (Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notification ) 
   {{$notification->data['text'] }}
 @endforeach
```

this gives error as undefined index text

but if i try to access text via

```
@foreach ($notification->data as $key => $data)
{{$data}}
@endforeach
```

it works

but why cant i can access data via `$notification->data['text']`

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `text` attribute directly like :

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notification )
    {{ $notification->text }}
    //Or use
    {{ $notification['text'] }}
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok try please `$notification->data->text`

Comment: Try also `json_decode( $notification->data )->text`.